# Call to system's arp command fails with shell_exec

Tags: php, mac-address, shell-exec

I has been searching a long time in Google but not get what I looking for. I have an local web application for business in different building of my office. My staff will use this application in local network with both wireless devices and desktop computer. 
But I want to give them access through only limited devices and machines.

I can get the MAC address of connected devices by passing their IP addresses to `arp`, for instance:

```
arp -n 192.168.10.12
```

in terminal.

But I can't get any output when I run same command in php script

```
$output = shell_exec('arp -n 192.168.10.12'); echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I tried some commands such as `ls -l /var/www` in `shell_exec` function, these commands display the same as in the command line. So my question is why I can't run `arp -n ipaddress` command and how to run it.

I can't check the MAC address via router because my business clients like to use my network when they come to my office.

Thanks in advance.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php) link.

Comment: Take a look into solution for MAC-addresses I've provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401945/is-it-possible-to-restrict-php-page-to-certain-devices/18402135#18402135

Comment: I have the same problem.  `/usr/sbin/arp -na` gives the list I want, but exec('/usr/sbin/arp -na') gives empty result.   exec('whoami') in php gives the same result as `whoami` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `www-user` is not allowed to use the `arp` command or reference to the full path.

Use its full path like `/usr/sbin/arp`.

It either works or sais no permission then. If no permission, 
search for `sudo` and let `www-user` access `arp`.

```
dan@big:/root$ /usr/sbin/arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress      Flags Mask            Iface
xxxx.xx.xx.xxxx  ether   00:00:XX:00:01:XX      C                     eth0

dan@big:/root$ arp
bash: arp: command not found
```

Comment: Thank DanFromGermany, I got it with ur help. 
but problem is it took 10s to return $macAddr
`$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ipAddress;
echo "<pre>".get_mac($ipAddress)."</pre>";
function get_mac($ipAddress){
 $macAddr=false;
 $output = shell_exec('/usr/sbin/arp');
 $lines=explode("\n", $output);
 foreach($lines as $line){
    $cols=preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
    if ($cols[0]==$ipAddress)
    {
     $macAddr=$cols[2];
    }
 }
 return $macAddr;
}`

can it be done with better performance? Anyway Thank. :)