# How to best secure my home automation webserver?

Tags: php, security, server, password-protection

I have set up a small raspberry pi home automation from scratch along with some ipcams to surveil my house.
All those are controlled by a small webpage (with relay switches and video feeds) i have set up that works very well within my home network.
I was thinking of setting up a dyndns account (as i dont have a static ip) in order to be able to access all those things remotely through 4G.
Obviously i dont just want to point an open port to my web page and just make it accessible online.
How to i make this secure?  Here are my thoughts:

- Do i set up a quick Joomla! site inside my network that ill have to log in every time? (or something similar - im just familiar with Joomla!)
- Is there some way to password protect the website with .htaccess? Is it safe? could you point me out to a guide?
- Is there some way to restrict access only to my cellphone's 4G mac address?
- Is there some way to set up some vpn or other "tunnel" between my phone and home? (I wouldnt want it to apply to all my phone's traffic though)
- Do i have this all wrong and there's some other awesome way to do what i need?

Please keep in mind that i would appreciate simplicity and ease of connection every time ill access the website. ie. i wouldnt want to log in every time i need to open my garage while driving near the house.

Lastly i was thinking of posting this in some other stack subforum but i ended up here, if you think there is some more suitable community please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to restrict PHP page to certain devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401945/is-it-possible-to-restrict-php-page-to-certain-devices)

Comment: @Pete it is one possible solution, but is it the preferred one compared to the alternatives?

Comment: MAC addresses can be spoofed.

Comment: Ok, so mac address option seems to be rejected. Also, in the solution you mention, it just restricts the app (or in my case index.php) from running, couldnt one just get access to the index.php file or other files and read what's in them? since he has normal access to the online directory?

Comment: I wouldn't set up a site quickly. Especially in your case. I wouldn't reject the mac address option but implement multiple security measures. MAC Address seems to be one option to consider. Despite that you could send a mail to yourself each time someone access your rasperry. So, should someone spoofed your MAC Address and accessed the server you at least will know about it. I have set up a simple site I use with someone else. It's not that bad if someone hacks it. However, to access content one have to authorize twice anyway. First htaccess, then with the personal account.

Comment: The surveillance system needs to be on an internal private network.  The web page that controls it needs to restrict external access to your device only.  VPN would be an ideal solution but do not know the complexity of setting that up (nor do I have the expertise to recommend any particular software).  If your web server gets hacked, then game over.  Therefore avoid software like Joomla that has a very bad security reputation.  Whatever software you have, you need to subscribe to their security email list and update whenever a serious vulnerability is known.

Answer (score 0):

Password protect it. However, hackers can hack the IP cameras. Find vulnerabilities in the software and patch them. Port forwarding to IP cameras should be safe. You can use Hamachi for a tunnel but it requires you to have a computer. You can restrict access by IP address. There will be guides on the Internet. Google is the best option for you.