# Restricting access to a PHP script

Tags: php, security, ionic-framework

I have a security-related question - I'm developing an app that populates its database by using a PHP script on a remote server. I wouldn't like to make the PHP script publicly available, but just use it from the specific mobile application (written with TypeScript using the Ionic Framework). How could I accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401945/is-it-possible-to-restrict-php-page-to-certain-devices/18402432#18402432

Answer (score 0):

Make your mobile application to provide with the query some kind of secret string / token. And your server side PHP script will not proceed without valid token provided from the request.

The token can be part of your POST/GET/HTTP header or so.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past to achieve something like this is to setup an API key system. You generate API keys server-side, and you lease out valid keys that you have generated to your application(s). You would then use that key in your application, and that would get sent to the server and parsed by a php script whenever you call the script from your mobile application. If the key is valid, then the request is valid.

There are some security considerations to think about, i.e what happens if someone gets your API key? Are you logging remote IP's (and fully qualified domain names) and API usage, will your system be able to invalidate the key whenever necessary? Is the API request utilising TLS connections?